# Associate rows of table into groups, with special element in each group

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a table `items (id, varchar name)`. I would like to create a way to group `item`s into groups. Each `item` should be in exactly one `group`. Each group should have at least one `item`, possibly multiple. Each `group` should have exactly one of its `item`s designated as special, and that `item` must be a member of that `group`. It should be possible to select any `item` as the selected `item`, and it should be possible to change which `item` of a `group` is the selected one.

I am using a recent version of MySQL, the `items` table uses InnoDB.

How can I encode those constraints into an SQL design? I know how to create an n-to-1 associative table, but I don't know how to encode the "exactly one special element" part.

My current attempt uses a table `group (id)` and

```
group_item (
  id,
  group_id,
  item_id,
  unique key item_id,
  selected enum("selected") null,
  unique key (group_id, selected)
  )
```

but that does not ensure at least one element is selected, and I'm not sure if that design goes in the right direction.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a good term to search for in order to find literature or code that tries to implement this sort of design - I've spent considerable time searching through Google and Stack Overflow as well as a few SQL books.

Comment: Please show some attempt at doing some part(s) of this. Please ask 1 specific clear question per post. PS item [i] is in group [g] and whether it is the special item is [s]

Comment: @philipxy what is non-specific about this question? I am only asking about one thing: how to design a grouping with a selected special item. There aren't multiple parallel goals here. There is only one goal with multiple constraints.

Comment: I proposed a base table holding the rows of the form (i, g, s) where "item [i] is in group [g] and whether it is the special item is [s]". So i & g are ids & s is boolean. In a relational DB a table (base or query result) holds the rows that satisfy (make a true statement from) a given (characteristic) predicate/function. We can't use (query or update) a DB without knowing these. You might find more under "characteristic function" (of a set). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation

Comment: Thanks. As the question indicates, I know how to build associative n-to-1 tables. However, the design you propose, which is exactly that, does not allow encoding the constraints that I mention in the question.

As someone who studied mathematics and knows SQL pretty well I don't really know what set builder notation has to do with what you said.

Comment: I said 'a base table holding the rows of the form (i, g, s) where "item [i] is in group [g] and whether it is the special item is [s]"'. That's a base table holding { (i,g,s) | item [i] is in group [g] and whether it is the special item is [s] }.

Comment: Another other obvious design is "item [i] is in group [g]" with (i) PK/UNIQUE & "item [i] is the special item of group [g]" with (i) & (g) PK/UNIQUE & FK (i,g) from the latter to the former. This allows much declarative SQL constraint definition. But there is also a (g) FK from the former to the latter so that requires a trigger in present SQL DBMSs. Also updates are multi-table. Etc re other designs. Alas "best" depends chaotically on details. (This question is likely a duplicate but likely hard to find.) PS Your question is not very clear about your design(s) (tables, constraints & updates).

Comment: @philipxy there is no design that should inform the design of the solution to this question. I want to find the best design.

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/266284)

Comment: I don't understand your last comment's 1st sentence. Given 1 design we can rearrange to others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution which, however, does not satisfy all the constraints.

1. Create a group table, let's `id` its identifier.
2. Add to the items table a foreign key for the group, `group_id`. This satisfy the constraint “Each item should be in exactly one group”.
3. The group table should have an attribute `selected_item`, foreign key for the item table. This satisfy the constraint “Each group should have exactly one of its items designated as special”.

The constraints that are not satisfied by this solution are:

1. Each group should have at least one item.
2. Each group should have exactly one of its items designated as special, and that item must be a member of that group.

These two constraints could be enforced by the application with two simple queries: the first constraint could be enforced by a query that checks or delete groups without any item, something like:

```
DELETE FROM groups g 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM items i WHERE i.group_id = g.id)
```

the second one with a query that checks that the `selected_item` in every group refers to some item that has that group has `group_id`. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM groups g
WHERE selected_item NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM items i WHERE i.group_id = g.id)
```

(possibly with an additional condition `AND selected_item IS NOT NULL` if the attribute can be nullable).

Alternatively, you could add triggers to enforce the constraints automatically.

Comment: Thanks. This is the design in the original question, however it leaves me dissatisfied and I hope there's a completely different design.

Comment: In the original question you describe three tables. In the above solutions there are only two tables.

Comment: That's true! I misread. However, funnily enough, this is the design I tried just before the one I described in my post, and I abandoned it due to empty groups.

Comment: I think that, given the limitations of the relational data model, it is impossible to find a solution that satisfies all the different constraints.  In a way or in another some constraint cannot be accommodated, so the only solutions that are not based on application checks should use triggers. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Items (
  item_id,
  group_id NOT NULL, -- "Each item should be in exactly one group"
  PRIMARY KEY(item_id)
  INDEX (group_id)
  )

CREATE TABLE Groups (
  group_id,
  special_item_id,  -- "the special item must be a member of that group"
  PRIMARY KEY(group_id)
  )
```

There is no need for a separate table mapping between items groups.

Those two table definitions give the minimal required for providing all the links required.  And they handle *some* of the constraints.

"change which item of a group is the selected one" -- `UPDATE Groups SET special_item_id = ... WHERE ...`

As for "Each group should have at least one item"; that is not enforced here.  You may need business logic for that.  Or perhaps a `FOREIGN KEY` could do it.  Or a `TRIGGER`.  Keep in mind that both `INSERTs` and `DELETEs` from each of the tables risk violating the requirement.

As for "special item is not a regular member of another group"  Ditto.

Comment: thanks. this design does not ensure that the special item is not a regular member of another group. basically, you've defined a rose tree with possible cycles.